# Angular cli polyfills use core-js rather than es6-shim

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to somehow configure the Cli to use core-js rather than es6-shim?

I have updated my package.json file, removed es6-shim and added core-js

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: no I am just trying to keep my project setup similar to the way the Google angular 2 team is. They moved away from es6-shim for core-js.

Comment: uhm, can't you just update angular-cli directly? there is a tutorial on how to do it on their page here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: I guess I could but we are considering standardizing the CLI across multiple teams and some of them are off site so it would be a bit of a pain to manage a custom version of the tool.

Comment: Not a custom version, just getting the latest one.

Comment: as @acdcjunior said, getting the latest one shouldn't be a nightmare since all you need to do is just be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the master branch is using `core-js` see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/b8ddeec1a9fd8fd0d6bfc296c14ada337e58ea01/addon/ng2/blueprints/ng2/files/package.json#L23).

It just has not been released to `npm`, it will be part of the release which contains the new webpack build system.

Comment: Is there anyway to know the estimate on when the webpack version is going to be released?

Comment: Hopefully this week, but it might be a tagged release `angular-cli@webpack`

Comment: UPDATE... you get can get it now... https://twitter.com/Brocco/status/760537695567306752